# Invalid Base64 when adding secret to a volume mount

Tags: azure, base64, certificate, mount, azure-keyvault

I have KeyVault in Azure with certificates and keys added as secrets. The certificates are in `.crt` format and the keys are in `.key` format. When trying to deploy the container through .yaml configuration in DevOps, I can retrieve the secrets from the key vault but I cannot include them to the volume. The exception is the following:

```
 The value of secret 'server.crt' in volume 'app-secrets' is not encoded in valid Base64 format.
```

The .yml deployment file looks like:

```
apiVersion: 2019-12-01
location: westeu
name: abcgroup
properties:
  containers:
  - name: abc
    properties:
      image: abc.azurecr.io/image:latest
      resources:
        requests:
          cpu: 1
          memoryInGb: 1.5
      ports:
      - port: 5000
      volumeMounts:
        - name: 'app-secrets'
          mountPath: '/mnt/secrets'
  osType: Linux
  ipAddress:
    type: Public
    ports:
    - protocol: tcp
      port: 5000
  volumes:
    - name: 'app-secrets'
      secret:
        ca.pem: $(ca-pem)
        server.crt: $(server-crt)
        server.key: $(server-priv-key)
  imageRegistryCredentials:
    - server: abc.azurecr.io
      username: abc
      password: abcd
tags: null
type: Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups
```

I tried uploading the certificate value both including the first and last line (with -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----) and without them, but the issues was the same.

Comment: Maybe your base64 certificate file not properly wrapped to 64 (if not wrong) character each lines. And try to charge eol to lf instead cr and vice versa. Or crlf. Also text encoding to utf-8 Unicode.

Comment: I have copied the value and put it as a secret in the KeyVault, I haven't uploaded the file directly

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you removed the following two lines from your base64 string:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- // remove this

(...)

-----END CERTIFICATE----- // and remove this
```

If the error persists, I recommend the use of one of the available online base64 validators.

I like base65.guru: https://base64.guru/tools/validator